# How to make image align with container's bottom even its height is greater than container's?

Tags: css

```
<div style="max-height:80px;overflow:hidden"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
```

The lower 20px of the above image will be hidden, aka the image is aligned with the top of the container. I want the image to be aligned with the bottom of the container, so the upper 20px will be hidden instead of the lower 20px.

The image's height in my real project is unknown, so I can not use margin/translate etc to reposition the image. Absolute position is definitely one of the ways, as well as jQuery, I just wonder if there is any other way, like vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

Wen,

You have to use relative and absolute path.

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="img" class="img_path" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container{position:relative; width:80px; height:80px; max-width:80px; max-height:80px; overflow:hidden; border:1px solid #ddd;}
.img_path{position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;}
```

For More Info [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/9ysfvu32/)

Comment: I was asking other than absolute position, is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: You want like this *{margin:0; padding:0;}
.container{height:120px; border:1px solid #333; margin:10px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;}
.img_path{vertical-align:bottom} Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/9ysfvu32/

Comment: No. In your fiddle, try to make one of the images 50x250, you will see the container has been extened to contain the enlarged image. What I want is when the image is larger (in height) than the container, then the exceeding part shall be hidden, and this exceeding part of the picture must be the upper part, becasue the pictures's bottom is aligned to the container's bottom.

Comment: Hey, that's not a problem. I did it for as per ur req only. Jus remove the height and check the same. Chk this link http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/9ysfvu32/

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't seem to me that your fiddle is working as I expect. The 50x250 image has forced the container to be larger than it is supposed to be (try set a height or max-height value less than 250 for the container and you will see the value gets ignored)